# How to store variables on a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that is running on a single thread currently. In this method I am storing variables using `HTTPContext.Current.Session["VariableName"] = "VariableValue"`

But now I want to run the same method above on multiple threads in parallel. For obvious reason I will not able to store my variables using above statement. Now I need to store such variables privately within single thread using same variable names. For Example

`Thread1 ValueofVar = "xyz";
Thread2 ValueofVar = "abc";
Thread3 ValueofVar = "jkl";`

Kindly suggest suitable solution to this issue that I am facing ?

Comment: Will local variables not suit your needs?

Comment: You can always preface your ["VariableName"] with some sort of thread key ["ThreadKey-VariableName"].

Comment: As I am using these variables into multiple methods so cannot create local variable, I need variables with global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Thread-Level storage constructs  for your variables, by which, your variables data will be only available on the scope of a `Thread` - for that, use either [`ThreadStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) or [`ThreadLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (.NET 4 and up).

Example of `ThreadLocal`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class ThreadLocalDemo
{
            static void Main()
        {
            ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
            {
                return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            });

            Action action = () =>
            {
                bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;

                Console.WriteLine("ThreadName = {0} {1}", ThreadName.Value, repeat ? "(repeat)" : "");
            };
            Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action);

            ThreadName.Dispose();
        }
}
```